# Powershell use foreach loop to add up variables

Tags: powershell

```
$var1 = 138
$var2 = 77
$var3 = 45
$var4 = 1048
.
.
.
$var77 = 8
```

How can i use the for loop here to add theses integer type variables?

Comment: Why do you have 77 variables defined and why is it important to use a `for` loop? :-)

Comment: hello, these are inputs from different parameters,

Comment: Assuming they are actually named like that and defined as parameters: `(Get-Variable var* -ValueOnly -Scope Local |Measure-Object -Sum).Sum`

Comment: that worked thank you!

Comment: For the future, look up [arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.1) for a big quality of life improvement.